# Ошибка - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null

Tags: javascript, html-select

пытаюсь значение select поместить в переменную, но мне выдает ошибку- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null, код html:

```
<select onchange="transaction()" id="сurrencyMain">

      <option value="0">Bitcoin</option>
      <option value="1023">Ether</option>
      <option value="1223">Bitcoin Cash</option>

    </select>
```

Код js:

```
function transaction() {
    var currencyMain = document.getElementById('currencyMain');
       var  addres_field = document.getElementById('address-field');
       var amount_bit = document.getElementById('amount-bit');
       var amount_rub = document.getElementById('amount-rub');
       var  description = document.getElementById('description');
       var transaction_fee = document.getElementById('transaction_fee');
       var  currencyTab = document.getElementById('currencyTab');

        var price = 0;
        price += parseInt(currencyMain.options[currencyMain.selectedIndex].value);
        currencyTab.innerHTML = price;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в `<select onchange="transaction()" id="сurrencyMain">` в `сurrencyMain` первая буква `с` - русская.

Comment: да, все верно, спасибо)